# Puppeteer Web Scraper returning null data

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am writing a program with puppeteer that takes song titles and artist names from youtube playlists using the following code:

```js
await page.goto(url);
let songs = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let results = [];
    let songTitle, songArtist;
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll('#meta');
    elements.forEach(el => {
        songTitle = el.querySelector('h4');
        songArtist = el.querySelector('#byline');
        if (songTitle) {
            results.push({
                title: songTitle.textContent,
                artist: songArtist.textContent
            });
        }
    });
    return results;
});
songs.forEach(song => {
    song.title = song.title.trim();
    song.artist = song.artist.trim();
});
songs.sort((a,b) => a.artist > b.artist ? 1 : -1);
console.table(songs);
```

The variable url is a link to a youtube playlist with 8 songs. I have run this program with that playlist and others before and it has worked fine. However, the past few days it has been returning a blank table, even though I have not modified this code. I have added more code to the end that works with the spotify web player, but that shouldn't effect the code I have already written, and some of it was already there before the YouTube part stopped working.

Is there something wrong with the code I wrote, or is it an issue with my wifi?

EDIT: I tried running the code with the Spotify part commented out, and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quality of the network connection was a good guess.

You need to wait for the elements loaded in the DOM before you'd start the scraping. If your network is extremely speedy: you will have success, otherwise it won't collect the desired content. You could use [`page.waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to make sure the scraping can be started.

```js
await page.goto(url);
await page.waitForSelector('#meta');
let songs = await page.evaluate(() => {
...
```